# SQL max size LONGTEXT

Tags: mysql, sql, longtext

I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Hospital_MedicalRecord(
  recNo CHAR(5),
  patient CHAR(9),
  doctor CHAR(9),
  enteredOn DATETIME NOT NULL,
  diagnosis LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  treatment TEXT(1000),
  PRIMARY KEY (recNo, patient),
  CONSTRAINT FK_patient FOREIGN KEY (patient) REFERENCES Hospital_Patient(NINumber),
  CONSTRAINT FK_doctor FOREIGN KEY (doctor) REFERENCES Hospital_Doctor(NINumber)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

How can one make `diagnosis` contain some long text but never more than 2^24 bytes? I've looked into `LONGTEXT` but I couldn't find a way to limit it since it can go up to 2^34 I believe?

Comment: You can add a trigger if you really feel compelled to distinguish between those two sizes.  In some very recent version of MySQL, you could also use a `check` constraint.

Comment: I will look into that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MEDIUMTEXT`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-overview.html

> `MEDIUMTEXT [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]`
>
> A `TEXT` column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2<sup>24</sup> − 1) characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte characters. Each `MEDIUMTEXT` value is stored using a 3-byte length prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.

The wording is a little strange. The length limit is really on bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 1):

LONGTEXT is limited to the maximum that the filesystem permits for a 32 bit system it is limited to 2^32 that is approximately 4.000.000.000 characters (if you do not use multi-byte characters), I have not calculated exactly.
Then you have MEDIUMTEXT with 2^24 characters .. around 16.000.000 characters. TEXT has a limit at 2^16 character that is much smaller, about 64.000 characters (if you do not have multibyte).
What You need is called MEDIUMTEXT